# C++ breaking a program up into functions

Tags: c++, function

My assignment is use 3 functions with parameters, as follows:

1. function calcRegBill – accepts one integer argument for the number of minutes used. Determines and returns the total amount due.
2. function calcPremBill – accepts two integer arguments, for the number of day minutes and number of night minutes used. Determines and returns the total amount due.
3. function printBill – accepts 4 arguments: a string account number, a character service code, an integer total number of minutes used, and an amount due. Note that this is a generic print bill function, which prints either a regular or premium bill, using the following format:

Account Number:    XXXX

Service Type:      Regular (or Premium, depending on the character received)

Total Minutes:     XXX

Amount Due:        $XXX.XX

Your main function will prompt the user for the account number and service code. Based on the service code, main will ask for the correct number of minutes, then call your functions above as needed to finish the job. In addition you must :

Incorporate a loop in your program to run the bill as many times as needed. You may do this either by a sentinel controlled loop, or with a counter controlled loop.

**I already built the program and tested it with everything in the main function of the program. I am just really confused about how to break it into the 3 separate functions and have it all still work. I am a total noob at C++**

Here is the program so far, I started to add the functions, but I do not believe they're right.

```
// Cell Bill Fun
// April 14, 2013

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double calcRegBill(int a);

double calcPremBill(int b, int c);

void printBill(string acctNumber, char serviceCode, int d, double e);

int main()
{

//declare variables for question 4

char serviceCode;
int acctNumber;
int minutes;
int dayMinutes;
int nightMinutes;
int charge;
int dayFee;
int nightFee;
double amtDue;


//get input
cout << "Please enter your information to calculate your cell phone bill ";
cout << "What is your account number? (please enter a 4-digit number-example 1234): ";
cin >> acctNumber;
cout << "Do you have regular or premium service? Enter r for regular service, p for   Premium.: ";
cin >> serviceCode;

//format output
cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed;
//output

 switch (serviceCode)
{
    case 'r':{
cout << "How many minutes did you use?: ";
cin >> minutes;
    if (minutes <= 50)
    amtDue = 10;
    else if (minutes > 50)
     amtDue=10+((minutes-50)*.20);
    else
        cout <<"You have input an invalid service code. Please type r for regular or p for premium service." << endl;

cout <<"Cellular Account #:" << acctNumber << endl;
cout <<"Type of Service: Regular" << endl;
cout <<"Total Minutes:" << minutes << endl;
cout <<"Amount Due: $"<< amtDue << endl;}
break;

case 'R':{
cout << "How many minutes did you use?: ";
cin >> minutes;
    if (minutes <= 50)
    amtDue = 10;
    else if (minutes > 50)
     amtDue=10+((minutes-50)*.20);
    else
        cout <<"You have input an invalid service code. Please type r for regular or p for premium service." << endl;

cout <<"Cellular Account #:" << acctNumber << endl;
cout <<"Type of Service: Regular" << endl;
cout <<"Total Minutes:" << minutes << endl;
cout <<"Amount Due: $"<< amtDue << endl;}
break;

case 'p':
    cout << "How many daytime minutes did you use?";
    cin >> dayMinutes;
    if (dayMinutes <= 75)
    dayFee = 0;
    else if (dayMinutes > 75)
    dayFee=((dayMinutes-75)*.10);
    cout << "How many night time minutes did you use?";
    cin >> nightMinutes;
    if (nightMinutes <= 100)
    nightFee = 0;
    else if (nightMinutes > 100)
    nightFee=((nightMinutes-100)*.05);
    else
        cout <<"You have input an invalid service code. Please type r for regular or p for premium service." << endl;

cout <<"Cellular Account #:" << acctNumber << endl;
cout <<"Type of Service: Premium" << endl;
cout <<"Total Minutes:" <<dayMinutes+nightMinutes << endl;
cout <<"Amount Due: $"<<25<<"+"<<dayFee<<"+"<<nightFee<<"= $"<<25+dayFee+nightFee << endl;
break;

case 'P':
cout << "How many daytime minutes did you use?";
    cin >> dayMinutes;
    if (dayMinutes <= 75)
    dayFee = 0;
    else if (dayMinutes > 75)
    dayFee=((dayMinutes-75)*.10);
    cout << "How many night time minutes did you use?";
    cin >> nightMinutes;
    if (nightMinutes <= 100)
    nightFee = 0;
    else if (nightMinutes > 100)
    nightFee=((nightMinutes-100)*.05);
    else
        cout <<"You have input an invalid service code. Please type r for regular or p for premium service." << endl;

cout <<"Cellular Account #:" << acctNumber << endl;
cout <<"Type of Service: Premium" << endl;
cout <<"Total Minutes:" <<dayMinutes+nightMinutes << endl;
cout <<"Amount Due: $"<<25<<"+"<<dayFee<<"+"<<nightFee<<"= $"<<25+dayFee+nightFee << endl;
break;

default:

cout << "Invalid Service Code. Enter r for regular service, p for Premium.";

}






return 0;

}
double calcRegBill(int a)

{


}
double calcPremBill(int b, int c)

{

}

void printBill(string acctNumber, char serviceCode, int d, double e )
{


return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure the issue is being communicated here. What's the problem? Do you not understand how functions work? Do you not understand how to pass arguments into a function and capture the return value? The conceptual break down of those three functions seem extremely straight forward, otherwise.

Comment: Exactly, I do not understand how to pass arguments into a function and capture the return value. I am using a textbook, but I find it confusing!

Comment: Ah, alright. Your instructor *really* needs to cover something that basic - a text book isn't quite appropriate. I'd be happy to help you in a chat, as that's a subject that should be taught in an interactive setting, not with a book. Let me see if I can't find a way to spawn a chatroom from this comment...

Comment: @SionSheevok: The only way i know of to branch a question off into its own room is to comment so much that it spawns that link.  :)  Lemme see if i can do it another way...

Comment: I'll try to do my best in a comment at least: Calling a function generally follows the form `FunctionName(Argument1, Argument2)` and so on with none, less, or more arguments. Where `Argument1` and `Argument2` are, you can write any expression that evaluates to the appropriate type. You can imagine that the return value of a function basically replaces the function where you call it. `double x = calcRegBill(0)` will pass `0` as the first argument to `calcRegBill` and then assign the return value of that call to `x`.

Comment: No problem. You may want to register on this site anyways, it'll be quite helpful, regardless of your knowledge or skill level.

Comment: Please do NOT edit your question to replace the entire contents with a "thanks". You've made it completely useless for anyone who wants to read it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions work by requesting data (the parameters you pass to them), and operating on this data, often by returning data.

For example, in the `case 'r':` block, instead of of your code, you would want to have:

```
cout << "How many minutes did you use?: ";
cin >> minutes;

amtDue = calcRegBill(minutes);

cout <<"Cellular Account #:" << acctNumber << endl;
cout <<"Type of Service: Regular" << endl;
cout <<"Total Minutes:" << minutes << endl;
cout <<"Amount Due: $"<< amtDue << endl;}
break;
```

Then, you can move the code that was previously in main to calculate amtDue into the `calcRegBill()` function, like this:

```
double calcRegBill(int minutes)
{
    double bill;

    if (a < 50)
        bill = 10;

    else
        bill = 10+((minutes-50)*.20);

    return bill;
}
```

The key here is that instead of calculating amtDue in the main function, you calculate it in the `calcRegBill` function and return it to the main function. Also, notice that I changed the name of the parameter from `a` to `minutes`. This improves clarity of its purpose in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The general structure of your program is mostly correct, and I am not really sure what you are asking.

For trouble shooting, write one of your functions and test it without all the other stuff.  For example, write calcRegBill...

Then write a very simple main:

```
int main() {
  cout << calcRegBill(3) << endl;
  cout << calcRegBill(11) << endl;
}
```

Did you get the values expected?  If so then move on to the next function.  Development is often about breaking the problem down into smaller manageable problems.

Comment: I'm not sure how to break down the program, I know how to call the functions within the main function, but what do I do about my switch (because there are now 2 separate places to calculate each type of bill, and then printing the bill out. In my program the user enters the code for the type of service they have, and then the minutes and the switch prints the output based on that. My question is how do I break it up into those 3 functions I listed and still have the program work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the flow of what you're doing.

1. First, you gather information. Note: The information you're looking for is the same, regardless of whether it's a premium or regular bill. You don't need to branch so early.
2. In order to calculate their bill, you branch based on premium or regular. Either way, you get back a `double` from this, so you can have a `double` variable that you store the return from `calcRegBill` or `calcPremBill` into. Declare this `double` variable before the branch, assign to it inside of your two branches (regular or premium).
3. Then, when you call `printBill`, you can pass this value and what type of bill it was.